# If always returns true

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm just experimenting a bit with C++ but I can't figure out why both if-statements return true:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Language?" << endl;
    string lang;
    cin >> lang;
    if(lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch")
    {
        cout << "Hallo Welt!";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(lang == "English" || "english")
    {
        cout << "Hello World!";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to C++ and stackoverflow so I'm sorry if that's an stupid or frequently asked question but I really don't know any further. Please help!

Comment: Which learning resource taught you to write if statements like this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit see the third word of the question

Comment: @MattMcNabb: What about it? Are you suggesting that "experimentation" removes the need for prior research here on Stack Overflow? That problems reached only by "guesswork programming" are worthy of anyone's time? Because if so I could not disagree more.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that OP was not learning from a resource. If this isn't worth your time just move onto another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch"
```

is wrong

```
lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch"
```

is right

"deutsch" alone returns the address of the string in memory. which is
always not equal to zero. which means true.

```
a == "hello" || "bob"
```

means

```
(a == "hello") || "bob"
```

regardless of what `a == "hello"` results in (true or false), `false || "bob"` becomes `false || pointer to "bob"`.  All non-null pointers are `true`, so this is `false || true` which is `true`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Language?" << endl;
    string lang;
    cin >> lang;
    if(lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch")
    {
        cout << "Hallo Welt!";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(lang == "English" || lang == "english")
    {
        cout << "Hello World!";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please explain to help the OP

Comment: What is the point of the statement `cout << "Hello World!";` - It will never get executed

Comment: Why return `false` when you should return an integer

Comment: that wasn't the question! that would be an another question. can be noted.

Comment: thats up to the developer. to return false. since the compiler allow it!

Comment: that's depend on what are you trying to do. I just answered the question and pointed to the problem you asked about.

Comment: I know, you have to replace `return false;` with `cout << "";` so the second statement can be executed.

Comment: I don't know why people down voted. I didn't change or pointed to other logical mistakes. because obviously this program is for testing and training purposes.

Comment: 2nd, I was going to edit and explain. I just posted an initial answer.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch"` is actually equivalent to `(lang == "Deutsch") || ("deutsch")`. The second part of the expression is a `const char*` with a non-zero value, which means it will evaluate to `true`. The same applies to your second `if` statement.

You meant to write `lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch"`.

Comment: IOW the `==` and `||` are independent binary infix operators, not part of a combined grammar construct. The kind of thing OP is trying to do is a set-inclusion test, which some languages can do with a different spelling - e.g. `2 in [1,2,3]` gives `True` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

`if(lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch")`

is interpreted by the compiler as this:

"IF lang is equal to "Deutsch" OR the memory address of the string "deutsch" is not equal to 0 THEN...

Remember that in C/C++ any expression that is not zero, is considered to be TRUE. The expression "deutsch" is a string constant, which as an expression, returns its starting address, which is likely not 0.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the if statement

```
if(lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch")
```

is equivalent to the following condition

```
if( ( lang == "Deutsch" ) ||(  "deutsch" ) )
```

Independing on whether the left subexpression of the operatir || will yield true of false the right subexpression is always yields `true` because string literals used in expressions are converted to pointers to their first characters. And because the address of a string literal is not equal to 0 then the subexpression is converted to boolean value true.

It is obvious that you mean the following condition

```
if(lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch")
```

According to the C++ Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, **pointer**, or
>   pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A
>   zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

And (5 Expressions)

> 9 Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator
>   that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1),
>   **array-to- pointer** (4.2), or function-to-pointer (4.3) standard 
>   conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

Take into account that string literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays as it is said in the quote they are converted to pointers in expressions.

Also you need to include header `<string>` and should exclude header `"windows.h"` because neither declaration from the header is used in the program.

Your program then it could be written the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Language?" << endl;

    string lang;
    cin >> lang;

    if ( lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch" )
    {
        cout << "Hallo Welt!" << endl;
    }
    else if ( lang == "English" || lang == "english" )
    {
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parts on either side of the `||` are evaluated as separate boolean expressions. First, your program checks whether `lang == "Deutsch"`. If that's false, it checks the next part, `"deutsch"`. Because this is a non-zero value, it evaluates as true.

Most other variables can be evaluated as boolean in specific (sometimes weird) ways. For an int, 0 is false, and anything else is true. For a string, the null or empty string is false, and anything else is true.

Your final statement should be `if(lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch")`.

Answer (score -1):

`if (lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch")` doesn't test what you expect.

it is equivalent to

```
if (lang == "Deutsch") {
    // Do stuff
} else if ("deutsch") {
    // Do same stuff
}
```

You wanted

```
if (lang == "Deutsch" || lang == "deutsch")
```

`"deutsch"` decays to a non null pointer so is always `true`.

Answer (score -1):

This code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Language?" << endl;
    string lang;
    cin >> lang;
    if(lang == "Deutsch" || "deutsch")
    {
        cout << "Hallo Welt!";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(lang == "English" || "english")
    {
        cout << "Hello World!";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is the same as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Language?" << endl;
    string lang;
    cin >> lang;
    cout << "Hallo Welt!" ;
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Corrected myself - but it is crap code to start with

Comment: This answer explains nothing at all. I'd expect much better from a 29.6k user. -1