# Why does the compiler execute the while loop again even when the condition is not getting satisfied?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
while(ans == 'Y' || 'y')
{
    cout<<"--MENU--"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Create a file"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Display that file"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter your choice-";
    cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            create();       //create and display functions are written above this, which are not required 
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
    }

    cout<<"Do you want the menu again?(Y or y for Yes and anything else for a No)";
    cin>>ans;
}
```

My expectation is:-

When the input is other than `Y` or `y` in `ans` in the last line, the control of the program should exit the loop and execute the next line...

However it executes while loop again. Why?

Suppose if the input is `n` in the last line, then the compiler should check whether `ans` contains the character `Y` or `y` and should exit the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035762/if-always-returns-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition inside the while `ans=='Y'||'y'` always evaluates to true.

It should actuay be: `ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'`

The way it was written, it only evaluates the equality comparison for `ans=='Y'` and then it does a logical or with 'y' which is interpreted as true (any non 0 value in C is considered true) so the whole condition is always evaluated true, regardless of the first part. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It is working now, seems like I am getting suspended again for asking a beginner question.

Comment: It's a valid question -- not sure why you'd get suspended

Comment: This is a common beginner mistake. Although I expect it would be difficult for a beginner to find a duplicate if they don't already know the answer..