# IF & else syntax in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I don't understand how "if statement with OR " works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); 
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    char a = ')';

    if(a=='('|| '{') cout<< "true";
    else cout<<"false";

    return 0;

}
```

My first thought was that the result would be "false"
but the program prints "true"

Comment: `if(a=='('|| '{')` should be `if (a == '(' || a == '{')`

Comment: You need to compare to `a` both times.

Comment: ***My first thought was that the result would be "false" but my COMPUTER says "true"*** that is because '{' is not zero so true. See what happens when you do this: `if ('{')  std::cout << "Got Here" << std::endl;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035762/if-always-returns-true) (Granted, that one deals with strings, not characters, but the idea/takeaway is the same.)

Answer (score 3):

What you have is essentially:

```
if(a=='(')
    cout<< "true";
else if('{')
    cout<< "true";
else cout<<"false";
```

So the first check is false, then the second check sees if '{' evaluates to true. My c++ is a little rusty, but I believe it will interpret anything other than false or 0 as true.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(a=='('|| '{') cout<< "true";
```

You have two problems with that statement.

---

#### 1. Operator precedence

Your condition is *not* like this:

```
a == ('(' || '{')
```

…but like this:

```
(a == '(') || '{'
```

---

#### 2. How operators work

But, even if it were like the first one, *that's just not how boolean operators work*.

Although it is common in English (and other human languages) to say things like:

> if X is Y or Z...

… that is not quite how boolean logic works.

Your approach would be parsed more like this:

> if X-is-Y, or Z...

And something like `(a == '(')` is going to give you a boolean, then *OR* that boolean with `'{'`. Not what you intended at all: a character like `'{'` is always "truthy", and anything OR'd with `true` is `true`, so that whole condition will always result in `true`.

What you need is:

> if X-is-Y, or X-is-Z

To accomplish this, rewrite your condition like this:

```
a == '(' || a == '{'
```