# C++: Is it possible to erase what was already printed on the terminal?

Tags: c++, text

I'm working on a text adventure game:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;

int main (){
cout << "Welcome to text adventure! Do you want to play? (y/n)\n";

char ansr;
cin >> ansr;

while (ansr == 'y' || 'Y'){
    cout << string (50, '\b');
    cout << "Okay, let's go!";
    return 0;
}
}
```

This works alright, but for readability I want the new text "okay, let's go!" to appear at the top of the screen. This is part of an educational assignment, but i really like my idea for my text adventure game. `system(CLS);` Does the job but i've been reading that there are some major portability issues with this since it can only work with windows.

I've tried resplacing `\n` with `\b` and it doesn't do anything because `\b` is only meant to erase what the console is typing. I'm wondering if there's a way the earlier things that were printed on the console. If not, are there any other alternatives to `system(CLS)` other than what I have on there to allow the new text to be bumped up to the top of the screen?

Comment: Standard C++ has no facilities to manipulate the screen in this way.  This type of screen control is either done by platform-dependent libraries or OS calls.

Comment: `ansr == 'y' || 'Y'` is a bug. This is always true.

Comment: i think `gotoxy()` from `<conio.h>` can still be used today.

Comment: @acegs No, conio.h does not exist.

Comment: On some compiler but its not standard `c++`

Comment: it's `c`. we used that years ago in `TURBOC` compiler. i don't know if there's a version that can be used alongside `c++` in compilers nowadays. i think they shouldn't remove those `gotoxy()` like functions since it's useful for text-only programs.

Comment: You might want to look up [ncurses](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses). On Windows, look for [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.org/). This gives you a *reasonably* portable way to manipulate the screen.

Comment: That's because as @PaulMcKenzie eludes, how the terminal is controlled is specific to that one terminal. (though there are a few standard models like those with VT100 emulation, etc..) There are 3 main approaches -- all NON-portable to the other. (1) conio.h for DOS/windows; and (2) ANSI escape sequences and (3) `tput` facilities for Unix/LInux terminals. Libraries like ncurses, attempt to standardize for Unix/Linux.

Comment: @acegs the last TurboC (Borland) release was 1997, nearly 2.5 decades ago.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- You also have the ConsoleAPI calls for MSWindows.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- right. Missed that one -- probably because I never used it `:)`

Comment: @drescherjm: yeah i noticed it always does this first one even when i put in a while loop for ```ansr == 'n' || ansr == 'n'```, why does it behave like this? I'm pretty new to c++.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin conio.h kinda dated and dowsn't work on new versions, though Win10 introduced Linux-sh terminal esc sequences. `curses` is just a wrapper around latter. SO it all depends on versions too

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035762/if-always-returns-true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035762/if-always-returns-true) should explain why `(ansr == 'y' || 'Y')` is a bug

Comment: `while (ansr == 'y' || 'Y')` is the same as `while ((ansr == 'y') || (true))` ... probably not what is intended.